# Angularjs ng-repeat not updating after array update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm not sure what I'm missing here but I'm trying to update a value inside an array, and then have this reflected in the repeater. Do I need to make a copy or something before applying the update in order for Angular to show the changes?

---sample json

```
  "lists": [
       {
        "name": "one",
        "enabled": true
       },
       {
        "name": "two",
        "enabled": false
       }
    ]
```

!-- code

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.lists[1].enabled = true;
});
},1);
```

!--- html

```
<span data-ng-repeat="list in lists | filter: {enabled: true}"></span>
```

Comment: please add the html code, if you use data-ng-repeat="item in items" and $items is an array it will update

Comment: code is far too disconnected without being able to see your scope and basic html

Comment: I expect the community can solve this if you can provide a jsfiddle of your problem

Comment: the repeater is generated from another controller. So I need to access that controller by reference, in order to refresh the repeater?

Comment: the code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/gHb9z/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the "other controller" you are talking about broadcast an event:

```
 $rootScope.$broadcast('listChange', listArray);
```

Then in the controller that controls your $scope.lists value, listen for the event:

```
  $scope.$on('listChange', function(event, list) {

       $scope.$apply(function() {
           // Update goes here
         });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you use angulars built-in timeout function $timeout.

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.lists[1].enabled = true;
},1);
```

Documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Answer (score 0):

Add your lists variable to the $scope inside your controller like this:

```
$scope.lists = [{
    "name": "one",
    "enabled": true
   },
   {
    "name": "two",
    "enabled": false
   }];
```

You also have to add something inside the <**span**>, because the Html you posted would not display anything. (You need to do something inside the <**span**> tag in order to show something)

```
<span ng-repeat="list in lists | filter:{enabled: true}">{{list.name}}</span>
```

Now when you update the lists variable, this will be reflected in the Html immediately.
Works fine for me. Hope i could help!